# Loading Data from API into listview on react native via redux

Tags: listview, react-native, redux

I wanted to create a simple App using RN, that just to load listview from API data.
the idea is:

- I fetch the API from my Action, then pass it to reducer on the payload
- On reducer i pass the data into my component
- On my component, I do the getData function on componentWillMount
- Then, after it loaded I will set dataSource of my listView using this data

But the problem is, the data wont loaded. its loaded upon calling in componentWillMount, but I cant figure out how to update my component or how to detect new props that created after the getData in componentWillMount finished it task.

this is my code snippet

```js
// 1) ProductCategoryAction.js

    
    export const getProductCategory = () => {
        return (dispatch) => {
            dispatch({ type: GET_PRODUCT_CATEGORY });

        fetch(CONFIG_GET_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_API)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => getProductCategorySuccess(dispatch, responseJson.result))
            //.then((responseJson) => console.log(responseJson.result))
            .catch(() => getProductCategoryFail(dispatch));
    }
    };



    const getProductCategorySuccess = (dispatch, product_categories) => {
        dispatch({
            type: GET_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_SUCCESS,
            payload: product_categories
        });
    };
    const getProductCategoryFail = (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ 
            type: GET_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_FAIL
        });
    };

// 2) ProductCategoryReducer.js

    export default (state=INITIAL_STATE, action) => {

    console.log(action);

    switch(action.type) {
        case GET_PRODUCT_CATEGORY:  
            return { ...state, loading: true, error:'' };
        case GET_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_SUCCESS:  
            return { ...state, ...INITIAL_STATE, product_categories: action.payload };
        case GET_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_FAIL:  
            return { ...state, error: 'Couldn\'t load category data.', loading: false };
        default: 
            return state;
    }
    };

// 3) ProductCategoryList.js

    

    class ProductCategoryList extends Component {
        componentWillMount() {
            this.props.getProductCategory();
        

        const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
            rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
        });

        this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.product_categories);
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        console.log(this.props);

        const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
            rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
        });

        this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.product_categories);
        
    }

    renderRow(product_category) {
        return <ProductCategoryListItem item={product_category} />
    }

    render() {
        if(this.props.loading) {
            return (
                <Spinner size="small" />
            );
        }
        if(this.props.error) {
            return (
                <View style={styles.errorWrapperStyle}>
                    <Text style={styles.errorTextStyle}>{this.props.error}</Text>
                </View>
            );
        }
        return (
            <ListView
                dataSource={ this.dataSource }
                renderRow={ this.renderRow }
                enableEmptySections={ true }
            />
        );
    }
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        errorTextStyle: {
            fontSize: 14,
            alignSelf: 'center',
            color: 'red'
        },
        errorWrapperStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#999999',
            padding: 2
        }
    });

    const mapStateToProps = ({ productCategories }) => {    
        const { product_categories, error, loading } = productCategories;
        return { product_categories, error, loading }
    }
    
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getProductCategory })(ProductCategoryList);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should get the understanding of [React Component life cycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle).

You are trying to fetch data from an api in `componentWillMount`, but the data is still fetching when `componentDidMount` life cycle has met where you create the dataSource variable. So you don't get any dataSource.

Remove your `componentDidMount` function and change the render function like this so whenever you get `product_categories`, the dataSource will get generated.

```
render() {
    let {loading, error, product_categories} = this.props;

    if(error) {
        return (
            <View style={styles.errorWrapperStyle}>
                <Text style={styles.errorTextStyle}>{error}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }

    if(product_categories & !loading){
        const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});

        this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(product_categories);

        return (
           <ListView
               dataSource={ this.dataSource }
               renderRow={ this.renderRow }
               enableEmptySections={ true }
           />
        );
    }
    return (
        <Spinner size="small" />
    );
}
```

Comment: hi Lasitha, the product category is returning [object Object],[object Object],... and it wont goes into if(product_categories & !loading) part.

Comment: I fix it with removing the product_categories, just using !loading if only

Comment: @baycisk great!

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to call componentWillReceiveProps after the props have updated

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
 this.loadPosts(nextProps)**HERE YOU CAN GET UPDATED PROPS**
},
```

when you data update at that time , you can access those data in nextprops